# Outlook uses the email subject as event title when sending calendar invite using ics attachment on Visualforce Email Template

Tags: outlook, salesforce, visualforce

I'm trying to send a calendar invite using VF template and using ICS attachment for the same but Event title uses Email subject and not the value I'm providing.

This runs perfectly on Gmail where Event title displays the value I'm providing but not on outlook.
Note: Other fields like location etc. is displayed correctly.

```
<messaging:emailTemplate subject="New Event"        recipientType="User"        
relatedToType="Sales_Team__c">    
<messaging:htmlEmailBody >
<b>Internal Comments</b><br/>
</messaging:htmlEmailBody>
<messaging:attachment filename="reminder.ics" inline="true" 
renderAs="text/calendar; method=REQUEST">BEGIN:VCALENDAR
METHOD:REQUEST
VERSION:2.0
PRODID::****
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:<apex:outputText value="{0,date,yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss}"><apex:param 
value="{!NOW()}"/></apex:outputText>Z
UID:{!JSENCODE(relatedTo.Cases__r.Name)}
DTSTART:<apex:outputText value="{0,date,yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss}"><apex:param 
value="{!relatedTo.Cases__r.Start_Date_Time__c}"/></apex:outputText>Z
DTEND:<apex:outputText value="{0,date,yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss}"><apex:param 
value="{!relatedTo.Cases__r.Start_Date_Time__c + (60/(24*60))}"/> 
</apex:outputText>Z
SUMMARY:AnyText
LOCATION:{!JSENCODE(relatedTo.Cases__r.HId__r.Name)}
STATUS:CONFIRMED
BEGIN:VALARM
TRIGGER:-P1D
ACTION:DISPLAY
DESCRIPTION:Reminder
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR 
</messaging:attachment>
</messaging:emailTemplate>
```

I expect invite on calendar and mail to display 'AnyText' (value in summary field) but it displays 'New Event' (email subject)

Comment: Seems like it should display "New Event" as that is the subject, no?

Comment: No. The email subject should be "New Event" and that is displayed coorectly. I'm talking of Title of the event, which is also displayed in calendar. Take a look here: https://douglascayers.com/2015/01/09/salesforce-send-calendar-invites-in-visualforce-email-templates/

Answer (score 0):

SUMMARY:<apex:outputText value="Interview with X"/>
type what you want to display in value.